# How to keep dynamically generated components from re-initializing when a new object is added

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

A portion of my app consists of dynamically generated components that are created inside a *ngFor loop like so:

```
<div *ngFor="let actionCategory of actionCategories | keyvalue">
    <h2>{{actionCategory.key}}</h2>
    <div *ngFor="let action of actionCategory.value | keyvalue">
        <app-gearset [action]="action"></app-gearset>
    </div>
    <button mat-button (click)="addComponent(actionCategory)">Add another set</button>
</div>
```

The user also has the option of adding more of these components by clicking the button tied to the `addComponent()` function, which looks as follows:

```
  addGearSetComponent(actionCategory) {
    this.actionCategories[actionCategory.key][Object.keys(this.actionCategories[actionCategory.key]).length] = {};
  }
```

This adds a new blank object to the end of the `actionCategory` object, adding a new component to the appropriate part of the app. The problem is that the state of the components that were already present is reset each time a new one is added.

Is there any way to keep the state of the previous components in the object intact when the object they are tied to is changed? Is there a better way to be dynamically generating components based on a complex object?

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Stack Overflow. _"the state of the components that were already present is reset each time a new one is added"_ - what you mean by state? If the state is `actionCategories`, then that should not be reset (it'll re-render based on same value). But if you are talking about some other UI state which is not part of the model, then you might need to store those states as well, either in another object or as an additional property in your existing model.

Comment: Thanks! The components keep track of their own state before submitting it via a service to the server, but if a user changes the state of the components, then adds a new one with the above button, the older components get re-rendered and their state is destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

After a few more hours of hunting through docs I came across the `trackBy` functionality. [trackBy][1]

It looks like by handing `trackBy` the following function I'm able to alter the way the DOM re-renders components:

```
trackAction(index, action) {
    return action ? action.key : undefined;
}
```

I'll admit I don't fully understand exactly how this works behind the scenes, but it's preventing components that were present on the page from being destroyed and re-rendered when a new one is added. I'll have to keep an eye out for performance issues, but I believe this will work for now! :)
[1]: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-ngfor/

Comment: My original question included precise examples of the code in question as well as a question pertaining to objects being re-generated in the DOM and losing their state.

Comment: Yeah, but if `trackBy` resolves your issue, it sounds like a different problem. `trackBy` can't be relied upon to preserve state as you suggest.

Comment: However `trackBy` can be used to prevent an object from being re-rendered in the DOM when the underlying object is changed, which is exactly what my question was pertaining to.

Comment: All I'm saying is that you're hanging yourself if your parent is dependent on its children never being re-rendered.